# My AngularJS app can not connect to the local elasticsearch, running at localhost:9200

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I try to develop an AngularJS JavaScript app, directly connecting to an elasticsearch back-end installed on the same machine. For local development I installed the latest elasticseach 5.0 and populated it with test data.

A simple request via `$http.get('http://localhost:9200/_search')` failed with the following error:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Accept":"*/*,"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate"},"url":"http://localhost:9200/_search"},"statusText":""}
```

Remark: I call my AngularJS app via Firefox, where I have disabled CORS in config. same behaviour on both dev enviroments I use: on my MacBook Pro and my WIN10 SurfacePro.

Comment: To be more precise: I bypassed CORS Errors on Firefox for testing in config by setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after 2h of desperateness ;-/

Simply deactivate CORS on Elasticsearch level, but of course this should never be done for production environments.

Add these two lines in ./config/elasticsearch.yml

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
```

Find here the vendors documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Answer (score 0):

If CORS is disabled then that is your problem. The same host on a different port is considered a different origin.